# insert content from object into specific div's with jQuery .each() loop

Tags: jquery, foreach, javascript-objects

I'd like to take the items from this object:

```
var things = {
    "thing1" : "I'm one",
    "thing2" : "I'm two",
    "thing3" : "I'm three",
}
```

And append them into this markup:

```
<div class="allthings">
<div class="thing1">other content first. </div>
<div class="thing2">other content first. </div>
<div class="thing3">other content first. </div>   
</div>
```

resulting in:

```
<div class="thing1">other content first. <p class="added">I'm one</p></div>
... etc.
```

I'm no good at .each() loops. What's the jQuery equivalent of:

"For each item in the object, find the div with the class matching the item's key and append the item's value as a paragraph with the class 'added'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$.each(things, function(key, value) {
    $("<p />").addClass("added").text(value).appendTo("." + key);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/exEbw/

---

**UPDATE.** For IDs use hash `#` character instead of dot `.` in `appendTo` selector:

```
$("<p />").addClass("added").text(value).appendTo("#" + key);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/exEbw/1/

Comment: thanks, sorry for the edit, i realized i had classes in the markup and id in my written description..

Comment: @nathanbweb Anyway, now you have both options :)

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do:

```
for (var i in things) $("."+i).append("<p class='added'>"+things[i]+"</p>");
```

A Jquery-only solution:

```
$.each(things,function(i,e) {$("."+i).append("<p class='added'>"+e+"</p>");});
```

Comment: A more informative solution with javascript implementation which is more optimal. But presented in aless readable form.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(things, function(k, v){
    var sel = '.' + k,
        $el = $(sel);
    $el.html($el.html() + '<p class="added">' + v + '</p>');
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7fqxS/)

Comment: BTW, it will be better to use `append()` instead of `html(html() + ...)`. Or if you like `html` method more, then using callback function is more preferable here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
jQuery.each(things, function(i,j) {
    $("." + i).append('<p class="added">'+j+'</p>');
});
```